# Travelling Salesman problem and Vehicle routing problems

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, vehicle-routing, traveling-salesman

[image]

Can someone explain to me why are we doing the $x_{ij}=1$ and and the constraint $U_j \geq u_i+1-n(1-x_{ij})$

Also do you have any books or sources in mind from where I could learn in more detail from scratch about these problems.

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/8120/interpretation-of-a-subtour-elimination-constraint-in-the-tsp

Comment: You can take a look at the paper https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/5363/OR-078-78.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y. It mentions your MTZ formulation and proposes a stronger formulation as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interpretation of a subtour elimination constraint in the TSP](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/8120/interpretation-of-a-subtour-elimination-constraint-in-the-tsp)